# how can I use Jmeter Server Agent With Other Applications?

Tags: jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0

and I need to use Perfmon Metrics Collector for my API testing. and I wanna know ask about how can I use Jmeter Server Agent With Other Applications? what should I change from my server agent that I downloaded from [here](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent?utm_source=Blog&utm_medium=BM_blog&utm_campaign=PerfMon)

Answer (score 0):

1. Start ServerAgent by launching `startAgent.bat` or `startAgent.sh` (depending on your operating system)
2. That's it, you can collect any [metric](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/blob/master/README.md#supported-metrics) using any [TCP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/TCP) or [UDP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/UDP) client software. The easiest way to test is using a [Telnet client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet#Telnet_clients)

   [image]

   as you can see these `8.9`, `9.5`, `9.2`, etc are values for the CPU load.
3. Normally people use [PerfMon Metrics Collector](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) listener for collecting and plotting the results, however if you're unwilling or unable to do it - you can use PerfMon Server Agent from any other application, just send the "interesting" metric name and parameters over TCP or UDP channel and start consuming results.

More information: [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)

Comment: great!! thanks!! I'll try this now.. thanks for the answer Dmitri T